# Puzzling SE not loading?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

​ ​​​​​ ​  ​ ​​​​​ ​​​​ ​​ ​​​​​​ ​  ​​ ​  ​    ​   ​ ​ ​​ ​​   ​   ​  ​​  ​​ ​ ​​ ​​​​​​  ​​  ​​  ​ ​​ ​  ​​   ​   ​ ​ ​   ​​ ​​  ​​ ​ ​  ​​ ​​​​ ​​​​​​  ​  ​ ​  ​​ ​ ​​ ​​​​​​  ​    ​   ​ ​ ​   ​ ​​​​ ​​​​

​ ​​​​​ ​  ​ ​​​​​ ​​​​ ​​ ​​​​​​ ​  ​​ ​  ​    ​   ​ ​ ​​ ​​   ​   ​  ​​  ​​ ​ ​​ ​​​​​​  ​​  ​​  ​ ​​ ​  ​​   ​   ​ ​ ​   ​​ ​​  ​​ ​ ​  ​​ ​​​​ ​​​​​​  ​  ​ ​  ​​ ​ ​​ ​​​​​​  ​    ​   ​ ​ ​   ​ ​​​​ ​​​​

​ ​​​​​ ​  ​ ​​​​​ ​​​​ ​​ ​​​​​​ ​  ​​ ​  ​    ​   ​ ​ ​​ ​​   ​   ​  ​​  ​​ ​ ​​ ​​​​​​  ​​  ​​  ​ ​​ ​  ​​   ​   ​ ​ ​   ​​ ​​  ​​ ​ ​  ​​ ​​​​ ​​​​​​  ​  ​ ​  ​​ ​ ​​ ​​​​​​  ​    ​   ​ ​ ​   ​ ​​​​ ​​​​

​ ​​​​​ ​  ​ ​​​​​ ​​​​ ​​ ​​​​​​ ​  ​​ ​  ​    ​   ​ ​ ​​ ​​   ​   ​  ​​  ​​ ​ ​​ ​​​​​​  ​​  ​​  ​ ​​ ​  ​​   ​   ​ ​ ​   ​​ ​​  ​​ ​ ​  ​​ ​​​​ ​​​​​​  ​  ​ ​  ​​ ​ ​​ ​​​​​​  ​    ​   ​ ​ ​   ​ ​​​​ ​​​​

​ ​​​​​ ​  ​ ​​​​​ ​​​​ ​​ ​​​​​​ ​  ​​ ​  ​    ​   ​ ​ ​​ ​​   ​   ​  ​​  ​​ ​ ​​ ​​​​​​  ​​  ​​  ​ ​​ ​  ​​   ​   ​ ​ ​   ​​ ​​  ​​ ​ ​  ​​ ​​​​ ​​​​​​  ​  ​ ​  ​​ ​ ​​ ​​​​​​  ​    ​   ​ ​ ​   ​ ​​​​ ​​​​

Comment: I've never attempted making this kind of puzzle before and I'm not sure the types of reactions I'm gonna get... so please be nice and leave constructive criticism!

Comment: Nice enigmatic puzzle.

Comment: Why is this blank?

Comment: @fasterthanlight -- That's the puzzle!

Comment: This looks like it should be a Meta post at first sight...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The question body contains a sequence of

> `\u200b` and `\u200c` characters repeated five times.

Mapping them to `1` and `0` respectively, we get

> [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
>      [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
>      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
>      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>      [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
>      [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
>      [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
>      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
>      [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
>      [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
>      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>      [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
>      [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
>      [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
>      [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
>      [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
>      [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
>      [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
>      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>      [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
>      [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
>      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>      [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
>      [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
>      [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
>      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
>
> Treating these as ASCII bits, this becomes the string:
>
>     Ah! You've figured me out!

Comment: Well... 8 minutes!

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Obviously these are outputs of some (probably Python) program. This is also what I would have done... so I'd say 8 minutes is a reasonable time. Nice puzzle!

Comment: Long time no see ...

Comment: How did you get the first part?

Comment: @WhatsUp Same here.

Comment: Mildly related [Whitespace](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Whitespace)

Comment: @SagarChand - selecting the place where the post text would have been gave me a bunch of invisible - but _selected_ - text. That already meant that there's some invisible character trickery going on. Which was my first idea anyway. Next step was right-click and "Inspect" the HTML code in the built in developer tools. Ahh! HTML entities! There we go....