# ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: This is the most unique question I've seen here, hahah

Comment: Congratulations on reaching the HNQ list with such a title :-)

Comment: I legit thought PSE had an error lol

Comment: @Anonymus25: I was certain it was an NBSP variant that wasn't being filtered out.

Comment: I can't solve it; my mind has gone blank.

Comment: I don't know what I love most: the question itself or the edit history

Comment: I couldn't even click on it...

Comment: This puzzle has been nominated for [Best Puzzles of 2022: January - March](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7323/79067)!

Comment: Haha! I know how you got this [idea](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/101261/78877).

Comment: @ACB Oh, I guess I forgot! But seriously, that's not where I got inspiration from for this puzzle... I actually got the idea from a post on MSE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105389/mmm-mmmmmmmmm-mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm-mmmmmmmm-mmmmm-mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm-mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This question has

> many instances of the character `U+2800 BRAILLE PATTERN BLANK`, occasionally separated by spaces.

If you

> count the number of consecutive copies of `BRAILLE PATTERN BLANK` there are, and convert it to letters (with A=1, B=2, etc), it spells out "YOU HAVE SOLVED THIS PUZZLE".

Comment: Title is spelling out "hi".

Comment: How do you tell the difference between the Unicode blank and a space in order to count them? Paste into a text editor that recognises control characters, or something else?

Comment: @HashimAziz, `unicode --max 0 '<paste text here>' | rg '^U\+' | uniq -c | rg BRA | awk '{print $1}' | perl -nE 'say chr(ord("a")+$_-1)`

Comment: @HashimAziz : It would be more proper to do it myself, but for convenience, I use https://babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html

Comment: I had no idea I could already read Braille

Comment: I decoded it (after reading this answer) with a simple Python program, but I'm wondering why the word "Puzzle" is always messed up? In the bounty message, it's "PUZR", and in the question body, it's "PUZO". What happened there?

Answer (score 31):

The cipher describes the phrase

> Drawing a complete blank!

And another answer is

> 

Comment: Not an answer. By any stretch of imagination.