# 

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

> 

*P.S. This was inspired by [the all-whitespace puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/114735/63368).*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The title and contents of the puzzle are made up of

> [Unicode tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tags_(Unicode_block)).

The title:

> [`Start your engines!`](https://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%F0%9F%8F%81%F3%A0%81%93%F3%A0%81%B4%F3%A0%81%A1%F3%A0%81%B2%F3%A0%81%B4%F3%A0%80%A0%F3%A0%81%B9%F3%A0%81%AF%F3%A0%81%B5%F3%A0%81%B2%F0%9F%8F%81%F3%A0%80%A0%F3%A0%81%A5%F3%A0%81%AE%F3%A0%81%A7%F3%A0%81%A9%F3%A0%81%AE%F3%A0%81%A5%F3%A0%81%B3%F3%A0%80%A1)

The body:

> [`You have solved this puzzle`](https://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%3E+%F3%A0%81%99%F3%A0%81%AF%F3%A0%81%B5%F3%A0%80%A0%F3%A0%81%A8%F3%A0%81%A1%F3%A0%81%B6%F3%A0%81%A5%F3%A0%80%A0%F3%A0%81%B3+%F3%A0%81%AF%F3%A0%81%AC%F3%A0%81%B6%F3%A0%81%A5%F3%A0%81%A4%F3%A0%80%A0%F3%A0%81%B4%F3%A0%81%A8%F3%A0%81%A9%F3%A0%81%B3+%F3%A0%80%A0%F3%A0%81%B0%F3%A0%81%B5%F3%A0%81%BA%F3%A0%81%BA%F3%A0%81%AC%F3%A0%81%A5++)

Comment: But on a chequered flag you stop. However, I'm impressed by Unicode magic such as this!