# I’ve lost my message, can you find it?

Tags: cipher

- - - - . . . . …. …. …. ….

 -- -- -- -- … … … … . . . . .- .- .- .- … … … … . . . . --. --. --. --.

 … … … … .. .. .. ..

 --- --- --- --- …- …- …- …- -… -… -… -… --- --- --- --- .. .. .. .. … … … … ..- ..- ..- ..-

Hint 1

> morse code

Hint 2

> Word scramble

Comment: I think I have seen this somewhere before, very similar concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

> THE MESSAGE IS OBVIOUS

Process:

> After decoding the morse code that's written, you get this:
>  TTTTEEEEHHHHMMMMSSSSEEEEAAAASSSSEEEEGGGGSSSSIIIIOOOOVVVVBBBBOOOOIIIISSSSUUUU
>  Which, after clearing out the repeated letters, gives us this:
>  TEHMSEASEGSIOVBOISU
>  Which is just a scrambled version of:
>  THE MESSAGE IS OBVIOUS

Comment: It just so happens I have a boring day at work, and I like Puzzling soooo... 
But really, cipher puzzles aren't all that creative, so the "standard decryption methods" often do quick work of those. [Meta post plug](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do) if you wish to see what could be seen as a fun cipher, [here's one of mine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116202/morse-code)