# Like Peyton Manning or Aaron Rodgers

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

```
   ↖
    Relevant title     Explanatory/flavor text (optional)
                      ↙
```

*This isn’t it (although I tried). Maybe [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114735)?*

```
         
1.              
imMum           

2.
(m=1.; w=the opposite of m)
  mmmmmm
  ↓↓↓↓↓↓                                ← Body
  VIRYZZ
  ZPVBNS                       
  WUADLE
 ↗↗↗↗↗↗
mmwwmm

(7 6 6)   ← optional checksum or other validation

     Useful tags         Single objectively correct
    ↙                      ↓ solution (you provide)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Part 1

> is a rebus for "minimum", being "M in imum".

Part 2

> we have m representing minimum, so w is maximum, the opposite of m. For the top mmmmmm, we take the minimum letter of each column (meaning the earliest in the alphabet) to spell out VIABLE. For the bottom mmwwmm, we take the minimum or maximum letter of each diagonal to spell out PUZZLE.

All together

> This gives MINIMUM VIABLE PUZZLE, which can be abbreviated to MVP - explaining the connection to the title, since Peyton Manning or Aaron Rodgers are the NFL players with the most MVP awards. The flavor text references the fact that this puzzle attempts to be as minimal as possible.

Comment: That's right, great work!