# But do puzzles really need visible or even highlitable text to be a good puzzle?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, steganography

---

$\color{white}{fillertextsigh}$

Comment: rot13(svyyregrkgfvtu)? I found some HTML tags in the source.

Comment: @Someone that's highlitable :)

Comment: Should this also be tagged steganography?

Comment: Done! My edit was accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This puzzle

> Actually contains many `<sup>` and `<\sup>`s, as well as a few `<sub>`s, which can be seen by pressing edit. Interpreting the first as a dot, and the second as a dash, and the `<sub>`s as a break, we get the following as morse code:
>
> -.-- --- ..- / .... .- ...- . / ... --- .-.. ...- . / -- -.-- / .--. ..- --.. --.. .-.. . -.-.--

Which translates to the final answer:

> YOU HAVE SOLVE MY PUZZLE!

Comment: Correct! I wasn't expecting this to be solvable this fast (since obviously this type of puzzle hasn't been used in years) but good job! :)))

Comment: @CrSb0001 I've been around long enough where that was the first thing I looked for :P

Comment: [Feb 5, 2022](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114735), less than two years ago.

Comment: This reminds me of one of my favourite UK cryptic crossword clues, which is "1. (5, 3, 4)".  rot13(Gur pyhr ahzore (1.) vf neovgenel).